# PhoneGap Build iOS Keychain access?

Tags: ios, security, cordova, keychain, phonegap-build

Am I able to use the iOS keychain in a PhoneGap Build app?  I would like to store sensitive information here, and I can't use cookies, sessions, or local storage for security.

I've been looking on the internet, but I can't find a way to access the iOS keychain.  Is this possible with PhoneGap build?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, not at this time. There is a plugin for Cordova [here](https://github.com/shazron/KeychainPlugin), but it has not been made available for Phonegap Build yet. Keep checking the [Phonegap Build plugin page](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins) for updates though.

Comment: That's what I found online...that alone may make me have to switch to from PG Build to the regular PhoneGap...  Thanks!

Comment: FYI - I just emailed the author of the plugin to see if he can submit it to PhoneGap Build. Thanks for finding that.